# Basic access to GPGPU from Java

Tags: java, gpgpu

I understand there are many sophisticated things that [GPGPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) can do and yes maybe the default Oracle JDK download doesn't have those things.  But where is the lower-level raw access to the hardware?

Java certainly must be accessing my graphics card in general.  I just want to do something like multiply an array of floating point numbers.  This is *not* some advanced graphics thing.  Java has [MIDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) built-in, and it works quite well.  Obviously, you still need to create your own music.

How can I access my GPU hardware with the default JDK?

Comment: Although this is a general question I have a Dell gaming laptop with a NVidia GEForce GTX.  The NVIDIA prog files directory appears to have cudaxxx dll display drivers.  There is also a OpenCL subdir which is empty and I could download NVIDIA OpenCL.

Comment: JOCL (mentioned in my response below) has Java bindings to OpenCL.

Answer (score 2):

The standard mechanism for accessing OS- and hardware-level resources from Java is [JNI](https://www.baeldung.com/jni).  JNI provides a "bridge" between C/C++ and Java. Improved [alternatives to JNI](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/04/08/state-of-ffi-java#enter-project-panama) are on the horizon, in [*Project Panama*](https://openjdk.org/projects/panama/).

There are also Java libraries available for accessing the GPU.  In particular, look at the [JOCL Project](http://www.jocl.org/).

You might find this article interesting: [Programming the GPU in Java, Java Magazine](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/programming-the-gpu-in-java)